# splitting string into different ngrams based on probabilities (python)

Tags: python, nltk, n-gram

**The problem:** I want to split a string with almost 2 million words into uni-, bi- and trigrams based on the probabilities of them co-occurring.

The string was initially part of a pandas df `text['description']`. I did some preprocessing (all lower case, remove special characters, white spaces, single letters, remove stopwords and those that only occur once in the whole text, lemmatize). After that, I put them all in one big blob using `text1 = " ".join(text['description'])`.

text1 = 'buyer opportunity create personalised ideal home accommodation arranged laterally lower groundfloor comprises reception room feature fireplace spacious separate kitchen utility area principal bedroom ensuite bathroom second bedroom ensuite shower room principal bedroom provides direct access communal patio lead onto private south west facing rear garden also accessible via side passageway priory road ideally positioned benefit shop restaurant cafe society west hampstead st john wood kilburn whilst combination jubilee line overgrou thameslink bakerloo line transport....'

I built a basic language model, which is a dictionary containing probabilities of words co-occuring:

```
# basic language model
from nltk import bigrams
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

# create a placeholder for model
model = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: 0))

# count frequency of co-occurrence
for w1, w2 in bigrams(text1.split(), pad_right=True, pad_left=True):
        model[w1][w2] += 1

# transform counts to probabilities
for w1 in model:
    total_count = float(sum(model[w1].values()))
    for w2 in model[w1]:
        model[w1][w2] /= total_count
```

That part runs very quickly. Now I want to iterate over each word and if two or three words are more likely to occur consecutively than they are not (e.g., probability > .05), I will make them a bigram or trigram, otherwise I'll keep them as unigram. **This part has now become very clunky and runs way too long. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to speed this up / simplify?**

```
def func():
    new_string = []
    append = new_string.append
    a = 1
    b = 1
    for i in range(len(text1.split())-2):
        if b == 0:
            b = 1 
            a = 0
            continue
        if a == 0:
            a = 1
            continue

        w1 = text1.split()[i]
        w2 = text1.split()[i+1]
        w3 = text1.split()[i+2]

        if model[w1][w2] > 0.5 and model[w2][w3] > 0.5:
            append(' '.join([w1,w2,w3]))
            b = 0
        elif model[w1][w2] > 0.5: 
            append(' '.join([w1,w2]))
            a = 0
        else: 
            append(w1)
            a = 1
            b = 1

    return new_string
```

Also the use of `a` and `b` seems silly, but I wasn't sure how to skip one or two items. I.e., whenever the first if condition is met, I append the trigram and want to skip the two words that have now become part of the trigram (and same logic for bigrams).